# why connman ipv4 settings are having dhcp by default

Tags: linux, yocto, rootfs, connman

I am using yocto rocko for my board
I was setting static ip using rc.local at startup .But after some time ip gets changed.
So i found that following file is culprit

```
/var/lib/connman/ethernet_*_cable/settings
```

In the file below line is causing issues :

> IPV4.method=dhcp

I changed dhcp to manual and everything is working fine.

How to change in yocto build or kernel or filesystem such that when i boot a new card its value is manual by default

Regards

Comment: why negative marking ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep doing it manually on startup you can use connmanctl. I use these commands:

```
connmanctl config ethernet_*_cable --ipv4 dhcp
connmanctl config ethernet_*_cable --ipv4 manual <ipaddress> <netmask> <gateway>
```

The * in ethernet_*_cable is the mac address without :'s.

I guess you could patch connman to go with static as default, but wouldn't that bring up all boards with the same IP, and not work if the adresses/routing on your network does not play well with the your static setup? IMHO it makes sense to leave it at DHCP so it can work everywhere, and then reconfigure in a script based on the logic of your choice.